# Wilson's theorem related problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> prove        $$18! \equiv -1  \pmod{437} $$

I do not want full solution to the above problem but if anybody can tell me  how we can approach to it, I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Note $437 = 19\cdot 23$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hints :

- $437=19\cdot 23$ (as proposed by Sean)
- Wilson's theorem :-)
- $19\cdot 20\cdot 21 \cdot 22=(-4)(-3)(-2)(-1)\pmod{23}$

Answer (score 4):

As noted by Sean, $\,427=19\cdot 23\,$, thus using Wilson' theorem twice:
$$(1)\,\,\,18!\cdot 19\cdot 20\cdot 21\cdot 22=22!=-1\pmod {23}\Longrightarrow $$
$$\Longrightarrow 18!=\frac{-1}{(-4)(-3)(-2)(-1)}=-\frac{1}{24}=-1\pmod {23} $$
$$(2)\,\,\,\,18!=-1\pmod {19}$$

Comment: Is this not a full solution?

Comment: Not yet...but almost. The gist of it all is number (1), as (2) is directly Wilson's Theorem

Comment: Indeed, this cqn be interpreted this way!!

Answer (score 0):

Wilson's Theorem: (p-1)! = -1 (mod p),   p: is a prime number

Note: When I write the "equal" (=) sign, I mean the congruence sign.....

437 is not a prime number: 437 = 19*23

For: 19
By Wilson's Theorem => 18! = -1 (mod 19)

For 23: 
By W.T => 22! = -1 (mod 23) => 22*21*20*19*18! = -1 (mod 23)

For 22 = -1 (mod 23)
For 21 = -2 (mod 23)
For 20 = -3 (mod 23)
For 19 = -4 (mod 23)

We multiply our reminders => (-1)*(-2)*(-3)*(-4) = 24

Back to our equation: 22*21*20*19*18! = -1 (mod 23) 
transformed to => (-1)*(-2)*(-3)*(-4) = 24 * 18! = -1 (mod 23)

For 24 = 1 (mod 23) (replace 24 by 1)

1 * 18! = -1 (mod 23)

So, 18! = -1 (mod 23)

Hope it helps you understand it more.